# Calendar to send email to user entering new item

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, list, workflow

My office has a 2010 SharePoint calendar for employees to request leave by adding a new item to the calendar (list with dates, etc). Currently, there is an alert that sends those new items to a leave folder (email address). We often get several copies of the same request because users aren't sure their request was sent. I want to have the user adding the new item (leave request) be copied on the email. I assume I can't use the already established alert since the recipient in this case would constantly change to whomever the user was. It's my understanding that a workflow would be the remedy to have the emails sent from instead of the alert we currently use. I just can't figure out how to have the email sent to the user in that specific request since it looks like you have to enter a specific email address. Any help is appreciated and thank you for taking the time to assist me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a simple one life workflow in SharePoint designer.

The step to add would be "Send an email", obviously. Now you need to open the email config window and set the " To" property to your common mailbox.

For the "Cc" property click the button "Add lookup", which should be at bottom-left in the window. Here find the option for current item creator and select the email ID.

Enter subject and body details. You can display the calendar item's start-end dates, title etc using a lookup as well.

Once you publish the workflow to run on item creation, you are good to go.

Comment: Nisarg, thank you for taking the time to help me out. I look forward to trying this on Monday and will repost then.